# Linking against libgfortran and libstdc++ at the same time, in a python extension (.so)

Tags: python, c++, c, gcc, linker

I am having trouble building my own python extension. Building this code worked before (on Debian 7 Wheezy), but is now failing (on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid).

The modules in question appear to link correctly, but I get an error on `import`. I have tried two linker lines, one with g++ (which gives me a missing symbol error for a fortran runtime function), and the other with gfortran (which gives me a missing symbol error for a runtime vtable.)

The module uses:

- some polymorphic C++ code written by me,
- a FORTRAN (90) routine from stripack, linked to C via a header file written by me using [yolinux's guide](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html),
- a Cython file to expose some python entry points to the routines.

Thus, it needs to be linked with both the C++ standard libraries and the FORTRAN runtime, and be built into a monolithic shared object file.

I use a python [build manager that I wrote myself](https://github.com/joe-jordan/complicated_build) to solve this problem: the currently published version generates the following linker line:

```
gfortran -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -pthread -shared \
-Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lc -lstdc++ cpp1.o cpp2.o f90.o pyx.o -o \
module.so
```

(with some files omitted and paths shortened.)

This yields the following import error:

```
ImportError: module.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
```

Which is [apparently](http://demangler.com/) a reference to "vtable for `__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info`". This means, I think, that the `-lstdc++` entry in the linker line is not doing its job correctly.

Similarly, I have tried to modify my build system to generate a g++ line linking against libgfortran like so:

```
c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lgfortran cpp1.o cpp2.o \
f90.o pyx.o -o module.so
```

Again, this gives me a missing symbol error:

```
ImportError: module.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done
```

---

I have also experimented with static linking, which gives an error at link time itself (like "unable to move symbol"), and initially I thought that the runtimes may be split over separate files and tried `-lfoo` for many foo. However, I've checked the `libgfortran.so` file on the linker path with `scanelf`, and it *does* contain the relevant symbol.

This method of linking used to work (on Debian Wheezy, also tested on Mac OS X 10.7 a long time ago.) I am struggling to understand how it can have broken on the latest ubuntu (with a newer GCC, 4.9).

Any ideas, theories and tests to help debug/solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Theory: It detects a conflict between the libraries and doesn't load the first one, with the warning somehow getting lost. I'd try to list all exported symbols from both (using `readelf` or `nm`), and cross-reference them.

Comment: The order of arguments matters in a command line. If A uses B, A should appear before B. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain/CompilerFlags#A-Wl.2C--as-needed

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thank you, spot on. If only ubuntu uses -Wl by default, that would explain why the same line worked on other OS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to [@Marc Glisse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918193/marc-glisse) for your comment: the order of the arguments is indeed wrong.

If the original `gfortran` line is modified so that the `-lc` and `-lstdc++` terms are last, the ImportError goes away. Thank you!